# Where to add the Wav header to data in a live audio server using c++ and qt?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, client-server

I know it's a very long question, but I really hope you have the patience to read it and help me as I seem to have hit a dead end here.

I am very to new to c++ client-server and Qt multimedia development side. I am trying to create a server that would allow audio streaming to a client using Qt.

Using Qt's `QAudioInput, QAudioDeviceInfo, QAudioFormat` classes I have learned how to record an audio very differently from what is given in the `QAudioRecorder` example. I have also learned how to add wav header to the raw audio data and make the audio playable. The function that I am using to add a wav header to the audio is as following:

```
void Server::rawToWavQT(QByteArray* arr, long samplingRate, long bytes)
{
    long chunksize=0x10;
    struct
    {
        unsigned short    wFormatTag;
        unsigned short    wChannels;
        unsigned long     dwSamplesPerSec;
        unsigned long     dwAvgBytesPerSec;
        unsigned short    wBlockAlign;
        unsigned short    wBitsPerSample;
    } fmt;

    long samplecount = bytes/2;
    long riffsize    = samplecount*2+0x24;
    long datasize    = samplecount*2;

    arr->append("RIFF");//    fwrite( "RIFF",     1, 4, wav );
    arr->append(QByteArray((const char*)&riffsize, 4));//    fwrite( &riffsize,  4, 1, wav );
    arr->append("WAVEfmt ");//    fwrite( "WAVEfmt ", 1, 8, wav );
    arr->append(QByteArray((const char*)&chunksize, 4));//    fwrite( &chunksize, 4, 1, wav );

    int bitsPerSample = 16;
    int bytesPerSample = bitsPerSample/8;
    int channel = 2;

    fmt.wFormatTag = 1;      // PCM
    fmt.wChannels  = channel;      // MONO
    fmt.dwSamplesPerSec  = samplingRate;
    fmt.dwAvgBytesPerSec = samplingRate*channel*bytesPerSample; // 16 bit
    fmt.wBlockAlign      = channel*bytesPerSample;
    fmt.wBitsPerSample   = bitsPerSample;

    arr->append(QByteArray((const char*)&fmt, sizeof(fmt)));//    fwrite( &fmt,      sizeof(fmt), 1, wav );
    arr->append("data");//    fwrite( "data",    1,           4, wav );
    arr->append(QByteArray((const char*)&datasize, 4));//    fwrite( &datasize, 4,           1, wav );
}
```

I also got an [example](https://github.com/antonypro/AudioStreaming/) of how to make a simple server-client communication using Qt. Using that project I have learned how the client-server communication is developed using Qt server and socket modules.

The main window class for the server is like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setFixedSize(size());
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> devices = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput);
    QAudioDeviceInfo devinfo = devices.at(0);
    input = new AudioInput(devinfo, this);
    quint16 port = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
    server = new Server(port, this);
    connect(input, SIGNAL(dataReady(QByteArray)), server, SLOT(writeData(QByteArray)));

    ui->comboBox->setEnabled(false);
    ui->lineEdit->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);
}
```

The audio data provider class is as the following:

```
AudioInput::AudioInput(QAudioDeviceInfo devinfo, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setSampleSize(8);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    audio = new QAudioInput(devinfo, format, this);
    audio->setBufferSize(8192);

    device = audio->start();
    connect(device, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(readyRead()));
}

void AudioInput::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray data;

    //Check the number of samples in input buffer
    qint64 len = audio->bytesReady();

    //Read sound samples from input device to buffer
    if (len > 0)
    {
        data.resize(len);
        device->read(data.data(), len);
    }

    emit dataReady(data);
}
```

And the Server class is as the following:

```
Server::Server(quint16 port, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    socket = 0;
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), SLOT(newConnection()));
    server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port);
}

void Server::newConnection()
{
    socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), socket, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(destroyed()), SLOT(zeropointer()));
}

void Server::zeropointer()
{
    socket = 0;
}

void Server::writeData(QByteArray data)
{
    if (socket)
        socket->write(data);
}
```

The problem I am facing now is in finding the appropriate stage to add the `wav` header when writing the data to serve in the server. I have tried adding the header in the `writeData` function by using the `rawToWavQT` function as shown above, but in the client side it's not quite working, I cannot hear any proper sound there. I even tried saving the audio data received at the client as wav file, but after saving it, I cannot produce any playable audio file and file itself is very small in comparison to what normally a .wav file should be.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Why do you need wav header data? When streaming audio, the format is usually negotiated before the streaming can start. A streaming receiver that needs wav header data is doomed to fail, as streaming audio is not the same as playing a wav file from a remote source.

Comment: Could you please show it in the code what I should change to negotiate the format before starting the streaming? @KubaOber

Comment: I'm the owner of the project that you used in your question, I made some changes to it. The modifications include bug fixes, multiple clients connected to the server, negotiation of audio settings and audio recording by the client.

Hope that helps to achieve what you want!

[See here](https://github.com/antonypro/AudioStreaming/)

Comment: Thank you so much @user2014561 . You should post this as an answer so I can accept it and others can see the answer in future and can get some help or never mind, I am posting it as an answer.

Comment: @user2014561 Could you please tell me exactly from where you got to learn all the technique for developing the audio streaming server that you developed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the owner of the project that you used in your question, I made some changes to it. The modifications include bug fixes, multiple clients connected to the server, negotiation of audio settings and audio recording by the client.

[See it here](https://github.com/antonypro/AudioStreaming/).

The server is a very basic implementation that I learned from some readings on the internet, some things that I understood from those readings and other things that I saw on the multimedia examples provided with Qt. No just one source!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, I just tried to run your project in a Ubuntu system, but in the client side it always complains saying "Got a buffer underflow!". Have you tried your code in Ubuntu? Have you faced this problem yet?

Comment: I'm planning to release a new version, but until it's done, you can try reduce the sample rate in the Server to 44100 hz or lower.

Comment: I have actually found the reason behind the problem. It's the latency that comes with data transfer through streaming. What happens is that in the client side the QAudioOutput object gets into idle state when there is a latency and the buffer at the state becomes empty. Because of this empty buffer it complains "Got a buffer underflow!".

Comment: I released a new version, plese try it and tell me if it works!